# multivariate control chart

Tags: multivariate-analysis, quality-control

I am trying to build a multivariate control chart but I did not find any good explanation of how to do that.

Starting with $x_0$ a part of the samples that are in control I compute $\mu_0$ and $\Sigma_0$ the mean and the covariance matrix.

Now with new data $x_n$ I compute $d= (\bar{x}_n-\mu_0)\Sigma^{-1}(\bar{x}_n-\mu_0)$ .

After this step I do not really know how to go further.

The best answer will be a theoretical explanation and an R or python code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure, if you're still interested in the topic, but I will provide a brief answer for you and other people that are interested in working with quality control charts (QCC), using `R` language. For a *theoretical introduction* to the topic, I would suggest reviewing the corresponding section of StatSoft's nice electronic textbook: http://www.uta.edu/faculty/sawasthi/Statistics/stquacon.html. For much more *advanced* treatment of the topic, I'd suggest [this relevant thesis](http://www.stat-athens.aueb.gr/~jpan/diatrives/Maravelakis/Index.html), titled *"An investigation of some characteristics of univariate and multivariate control charts"* (see links to PDF chapters).

Traditionally, `R` *ecosystem* offers a wide *variety of packages* to choose from for a specific domain. This applies to the QCC analysis as well. Most frequently used package for QCC analysis is `qcc` (Quality Control Charts), however there many other packages with varying ranges of functionality:

- `IQCC`: Improved Quality Control Charts
- `MSQC`: Multivariate Statistical Quality Control
- `qcr`: Quality control and reliability
- `qualityTools`: Statistical Methods for Quality Science
- `SPCadjust`: Functions for calibrating control charts
- `CMPControl`: Control Charts for Conway-Maxwell-Poisson Distribution
- `edcc`: Economic Design of Control Charts
- `MetaQC`: Objective Quality Control and Inclusion/Exclusion Criteria for Genomic Meta-Analysis
- `graphicsQC`: Quality Control for Graphics in R
- `QCGWAS`: Quality Control of Genome Wide Association Study results
- `GWAtoolbox`: GWAS Quality Control
- `qAnalyst` (removed from CRAN)
- `SixSigma`: Six Sigma Tools for Quality and Process Improvement
- `qicharts`: Quality Improvement Charts

For `qcc` there is a hard-to-find [vignette](http://www.stat.unipg.it/luca/misc/Rnews_2004-1-pag11-17.pdf) by Luca Scrucca, which can be complemented by [this blog post](http://blog.yhathq.com/posts/quality-control-in-r.html). For those, considering using QCC in *educational setting*, there is an [interesting paper](http://pareonline.net/getvn.asp?v=16&n=15), describing the process (no code, though). Finally, anyone, interested in using QCC in a larger context of *SixSigma* and in `R` environment, the book ["Six Sigma with R: Statistical engineering for process improvement"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1461436516), published by Springer, might be helpful.

Comment: +1, that a great list for reference, thank you! I recently found out that `qicharts` is now superceded by `qicharts2` by the same author. Also, `qualityTools` seems to have been removed from CRAN.

Comment: @COOLSerdash It's my pleasure. I'm happy that you found my answer useful.